# -d foo-* within single and double square brackets

Tags: bash, wildcards, test

I just discovered that in bash,`[[ -d foo-* ]]` returns false (`$?` set to 1) even if a directory named `foo-bar` exists while `[ -d foo-* ]` returns true (`$?` set to 0)

I have to admit that I was surprised as I expected both versions to return true.

What is the rational behind this differing outcome?

Comment: See also the `bash` manual about `[[ ... ]]` where it says "Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the
              words between the `[[` and `]]`".

Comment: I missed that. Thanks for the clarification.